# How to replace words using regex with Xceed Docx

Tags: c#, ms-word, docx, xceed

I have multiple words in a word document and they all start and end with "$", for example `$name$`.
I'm trying to replace all such occurrences with an empty string. How can I go about this? Snippet of what I tried below and nothing happened. I'm using the free version.

```
using (DocX document = DocX.Load("Example.docx"))
 {
    String pattern = Regex.Escape("$") + ".+" + Regex.Escape("$");
    document.ReplaceText(pattern, "",false, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
 }
```

Comment: @PrasadTelkikar I just tried and didnt work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this pattern: `\$.+?\$`
In your code it can looks like:

```
String pattern = Regex.Escape("$") + ".+?" + Regex.Escape("$");
```

Comment: Not working either. Very strange, if I target a specific word for example  `document.ReplaceText("$name$", "",false, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);` everything works as expected and the single word is replaced

Comment: I don't know how works DocX, but this code works fine: `String pattern = Regex.Escape("$") + ".+?" + Regex.Escape("$");
var result = Regex.Replace("$name$ asdsad $qwe$", pattern, "");`

Answer (score 0):

Okay looks like `ReplaceText` expects a function when using regex. I've got it working

```
string WordCheck(string find)
{
 return "";
}

String pattern = Regex.Escape("$") + ".+?" + Regex.Escape("$");
document.ReplaceText(@"\$.+?\$",WordCheck,false, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```